# Error running React-native project in WebStorm

Tags: react-native, webstorm

This project I can run fine in command line, but if I run it using WebStorm, there will be an error like the following image:

[image: error-image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't set run/debug configurations. I run a react-native project as a node js. It run successfully when I set the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your webstorm is still using ecmascript 5.1 for javascript which does not support import keyword that is why u r getting this error.
U can fix it by going to preferences(on mac) and file->settings->language and frameworks->javascript change javascript language version from ecma5.1 to ecma6 or react jsx

Comment: I had been set it.

Comment: The error is from Node.js and not from the editor, so it's not related to WebStorm configuration.